# How to cap abandoned drain stack vent flashing

Tags: roof, vent, sewer, flashing

[image: roof vent]

I have an abandoned drain vent with the pipe removed and am wanting to somehow cap it without removing all surrounding shingles and re-shingling. Does any product exist that is made to cap an abandoned roof vent flashing? Thank you.

Comment: No product exists to cap that.  When no longer needed the vent and flashing are removed and new shingles installed.

Comment: Why not just remove it and get some decking and shingles?

Answer (score 2):

Find a Tupperware bowl of the right size, and a tube of construction glue.
Glue the bowl over the hole.
Enjoy the satisfaction that comes from a job well done.

Comment: "Enjoy the satisfaction that comes from a job well done" lmao

Answer (score 1):

Install a short piece of PVC pipe of the correct size into the flashing.  Use pipe strap to fix the bottom of it to the rafters so it won't lift out or move.  Replace the damaged gasket in your picture with a new repair one.  Then glue a PVC cap to the top of the pipe.

Note, the question was "how".  I don't have the experience to tell you if this is easier than re-shingling or if one or the other will give better results.  My thoughts on that:

- I won't climb on my roof, and if I'm paying someone to go up there, may as well do it properly and permanently.    If I was comfortable walking on the roof but not comfortable doing shingling, which would be an odd combination, maybe I'd repair it this way.
- A capped vent pipe is going to attract negative comments from inspectors who won't take the time to inspect where it goes.  This alone is probably a good reason not to do it.   When you sell or refinance etc, you may have to deal with these comments or may be forced by the buyer/lender/etc to re-do it.

Comment: "A capped vent pipe is going to attract negative comments from inspectors who won't take the time to inspect where it goes." this is a very very good point. I did not even think of that. Your idea is the best when compared to the other answers. The reason I did not do that initially is because I was afraid of condensation occurring on the inside of the "dummy" pipe.